# Panel data - when are $N$ and $T$ are "small" or "large"?

Tags: references, panel-data

I have a panel with $N=30$ and $T=30$ (possibly lower, the older data might turn out to be more of a hindrance than help). All of the "classifications" I encountered are very informal, dealing in terms like "small" or "large". From what I gathered, the cases of most theoretical concern seem to be $N \to \infty$ with fixed $T$ or both $N,T \to \infty$. But then for a relatively small panel like mine, does it even make sense to pursue these frameworks, or would I be better off looking for another approach? I'd be grateful for any references or advice.

Comment: I would not expect a clear-cut answer here - the extent to which asymptotics are a reliable guide in finite samples depends on further issues like signal to noise ratios such that there cannot really be a hard and fast rule.

Comment: @ChristophHanck Thanks. If that's the case, than what test would you suggest I run on my data to determine the course of action?

Comment: I am sorry not to be able to offer a specific answer - there is no magic solution to the issue that little data means little information so little potential insight...some pointers: bootstrapping sometimes leads to better approximations in finite sample settings. If you have prior information, try a Bayesian approach. All that said, what you precisely plan to do is not known to us as it stands.